# Need help converting Tradingview pine script from version 2 to version 5

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am new to TradingView Pine scripting.
I am seeking for help with a pine script which is on version 2 right now but I am trying convert it into Version 5 and is having so many compilation errors.

Below is the complete script I am trying to convert from V2 to V5 and error I am facing.
i'm getting these errors while converting
**Conversion failed, reason: Source pine is incorrect. line 12: Variable `sum` was declared with integer type. Cannot assign it expression of type series**
'''

```
//@version=2
study("Trend Signal", overlay=true)
RISK= input(title="RISK", type=integer, defval=14)
value10=3+RISK*2
value11=value10
x1=67+RISK
x2=33-RISK

range(length) =>
    sum = 0
    for i = 1 to length-1
        sum := sum + abs(high[i]-low[i])
    sum / length

MRO1(length, range) =>
    true_count = 0
    counter = 0
    for i = 1 to length-1
        x = if abs(open[i]-close[i+1]) >= range*2.0
            true_count := true_count + 1
            counter = i
            break
    mro = if true_count >= 1
        counter
    else
        -1  
mro
MRO2(length, range) =>
    true_count = 0
    counter = 0
    for i = 1 to length-1
        x = if abs(close[i+3]-close[i]) >= range*4.6
            true_count := true_count + 1
            counter = i
            break
    mro = if true_count >= 1
        counter
    else
        -1  
    mro

wpr(length) =>
    upper = highest(length)
    lower = lowest(length)
    out = 100 * (close - upper) / (upper - lower)
    out
    
rng = range(10)
mro1=MRO1(10,rng)
mro2=MRO2(7,rng)

rez = if mro1>-1
    3
else
    value10
    
value11:=rez
rez1 = if mro2>-1
    4
else
    value10
value11:=rez1

value2 = 100-abs(wpr(value10))

Table_value2=value2

notset=false
ii1 = 1
for i1 = 1 to 300
    if ((Table_value2[i1] < x2 or Table_value2[i1] > x1) and notset==false)
        notset:=true
        ii1 := i1

z=Table_value2[ii1]
up = if value2 < x2
    if Table_value2[ii1] > x1
        ii1
    else
        0
else
    0


plotshape(up, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, color=aqua, text="Sell")

dn = if value2 > x1
    if Table_value2[ii1] < x2
        ii1
    else
        0
else
    0


plotshape(dn, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, color=aqua, text="Buy")
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to `v3` first. Just change `//@version=2` to `//@version=3` and it should compile.

After that use the auto converter that is provided by Tradingview to upgrade it to `v4` and then same thing for `v5`.

Before converting to `v4`, make sure to make the following changes:

`sum=0` to `sum=0.0`:

```
range(length) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 1 to length - 1 by 1
        sum := sum + abs(high[i] - low[i])
        sum
    sum / length
```

Do the following in both `MRO` functions. `x` should be removed because nothing is assigned to it.

```
if abs(open[i] - close[i + 1]) >= range * 2.0
    true_count := true_count + 1
    counter = i
    break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem. successfully converted to version 5

Answer (score 0):

```html
//@version=5
indicator('Trend Signal', overlay=true)

RISK = input(title='RISK', defval=14)

value10 = 3 + RISK * 2
value11 = value10
x1 = 67 + RISK
x2 = 33 - RISK

range_1(length) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 1 to length - 1 by 1
        sum += math.abs(high[i] - low[i])
        sum
    sum / length

MRO1(length, range_2) =>
    true_count = 0
    counter = 0
    for i = 1 to length - 1 by 1
        x = math.abs(open[i] - close[i + 1])
        if x >= range_2 * 2.0
            true_count += 1
            counter := i
            break
    mro = true_count >= 1 ? counter : -1
    mro

MRO2(length, range_3) =>
    true_count = 0
    counter = 0
    for i = 1 to length - 1 by 1
        x = math.abs(close[i + 3] - close[i])
        if x >= range_3 * 4.6
            true_count += 1
            counter := i
            break
    mro = true_count >= 1 ? counter : -1
    mro

wpr(length) =>
    upper = ta.highest(length)
    lower = ta.lowest(length)
    100 * (close - upper) / (upper - lower)

rng = range_1(10)
mro1 = MRO1(10, rng)
mro2 = MRO2(7, rng)

rez = mro1 > -1 ? 3 : value10
value11 := rez

rez1 = mro2 > -1 ? 4 : value10
value11 := rez1

value2 = 100 - math.abs(wpr(value10))

Table_value2 = value2

notset = false
ii1 = 1
for i1 = 1 to 300 by 1
    if Table_value2[i1] < x2 or Table_value2[i1] > x1
        notset := true
        ii1 := i1
        break

z = Table_value2[ii1]
up = value2 < x2 ? Table_value2[ii1] > x1 ? ii1 : 0 : 0

plotshape(up, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, color=color.new(color.white, 0), text='Sell')

dn = value2 > x1 ? Table_value2[ii1] < x2 ? ii1 : 0 : 0

plotshape(dn, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, color=color.new(#3aff40, 0), text='Buy')

// Add moving averages
ma1 = ta.sma(close, 21)
ma2 = ta.sma(close, 50)

// Plot moving averages
plot(ma1, color=color.rgb(0, 255, 42), linewidth=2)
plot(ma2, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).